# Allowing a button to be pressed more than once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a word generator for a project and it will function similarly to [this page](http://watchout4snakes.com/wo4snakes/Random/RandomWord) where every time ther button is clicked the word will refresh. In my code it works the first time you press the button but after that it doesn't work.

Is there something I am missing, any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Miles

```js
var background1 = document.querySelector(".outer-1");
var background2 = document.querySelector(".outer-2");
var word1 = document.querySelector(".inner-1");
var word2 = document.querySelector(".inner-2");

var button = document.querySelector(".button")

colour();

function colour() {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    word1.textContent = randomWordLeft;
    word2.textContent = randomWordRight;
    word1.setAttribute("style", "color: yellow");
    word2.setAttribute("style", "color: green");
    background1.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green");
    background2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow");
  })

}

var leftArr = [

  "WHISKEY",
  "GIN",
  "VODKA",
  "APEROL",
  "CAMPARI",
  "LAGER",
  "ALE",
  "WINE",
  "MEZCAL",
  "TEQUILA",
  "PIZZA",
  "FRIED CHICKEN",
  "TOAST",
  "ICE CREAM",
  "CHIPS",
  "STEAK",
  "SALMON",
  "CAVIAR",
  "SUSHI",
  "PEANUT BUTTER",
  "MAYONAISE",
  "KETCHUP",
  "MARMITE"
];

var rightArr = [

  "MUSTARD",
  "SOYA SAUCE",
  "WASABI",
  "SEAWEED",
  "TURMERIC",
  "VOLCANIC ASH",
  "WATER LILY SEEDS",
  "SCOTCH BONNET",
  "BIRDS EYE CHILLI",
  "HIMALAYAN PINK SALT",
  "CHARCOAL",
  "KOMBUCHA",
  "MATCHA TEA",
  "COLA",
  "MOON MILK",
  "MILKSHAKE",
  "MORINGA",
  "DRAGON FRUIT",
  "JACK FRUIT",
  "GUAVA",
  "DURIAN",
  "LYCHEE",
  "BLUE JAVA"

];


var randomWordLeft = leftArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * leftArr.length)];

var randomWordRight = rightArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * rightArr.length)];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gen2</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="title">
    <div class="header-1">Mash Made </div>
    <div class="header-2">in heaven</div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-1">
    <div class="inner-1">Toast</div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-2">
    <div class="inner-2">Gin</div>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Mash!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are generating random world only once. You need to do that on each click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var background1 = document.querySelector(".outer-1");
var background2 = document.querySelector(".outer-2");
var word1 = document.querySelector(".inner-1");
var word2 = document.querySelector(".inner-2");

var button = document.querySelector(".button")
var leftArr = [

  "WHISKEY",
  "GIN",
  "VODKA",
  "APEROL",
  "CAMPARI",
  "LAGER",
  "ALE",
  "WINE",
  "MEZCAL",
  "TEQUILA",
  "PIZZA",
  "FRIED CHICKEN",
  "TOAST",
  "ICE CREAM",
  "CHIPS",
  "STEAK",
  "SALMON",
  "CAVIAR",
  "SUSHI",
  "PEANUT BUTTER",
  "MAYONAISE",
  "KETCHUP",
  "MARMITE"
];

var rightArr = [

  "MUSTARD",
  "SOYA SAUCE",
  "WASABI",
  "SEAWEED",
  "TURMERIC",
  "VOLCANIC ASH",
  "WATER LILY SEEDS",
  "SCOTCH BONNET",
  "BIRDS EYE CHILLI",
  "HIMALAYAN PINK SALT",
  "CHARCOAL",
  "KOMBUCHA",
  "MATCHA TEA",
  "COLA",
  "MOON MILK",
  "MILKSHAKE",
  "MORINGA",
  "DRAGON FRUIT",
  "JACK FRUIT",
  "GUAVA",
  "DURIAN",
  "LYCHEE",
  "BLUE JAVA"

];
colour();

function colour() {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
var randomWordLeft = leftArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * leftArr.length)];

var randomWordRight = rightArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * rightArr.length)];
    word1.textContent = randomWordLeft;
    word2.textContent = randomWordRight;
    word1.setAttribute("style", "color: yellow");
    word2.setAttribute("style", "color: green");
    background1.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green");
    background2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow");
  })

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gen2</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="title">
    <div class="header-1">Mash Made </div>
    <div class="header-2">in heaven</div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-1">
    <div class="inner-1">Toast</div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-2">
    <div class="inner-2">Gin</div>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Mash!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You Just needed to put your variables inside the function so, it gets created each time you create the function and "randomWordLeft", "randomWordRight" have new values to display

Answer (score 1):

- Move the random logic into your `colour` function. No wait, call it `randomText` instead!
- Remove the click handler from the function
- Pass the function name to the click handler `button.addEventListener('click', randomText)`
- Init `randomText()`
- Use `style.cssText = 'cssString'` to set your styles easily (or rather use CSS Styles)

```js
var w1 = ["WHISKEY", "GIN", "VODKA", "APEROL", "CAMPARI", "LAGER", "ALE", "WINE", "MEZCAL", "TEQUILA", "PIZZA", "FRIED CHICKEN", "TOAST", "ICE CREAM", "CHIPS", "STEAK", "SALMON", "CAVIAR", "SUSHI", "PEANUT BUTTER", "MAYONAISE", "KETCHUP", "MARMI"];
var w2 = ["MUSTARD", "SOYA SAUCE", "WASABI", "SEAWEED", "TURMERIC", "VOLCANIC ASH", "WATER LILY SEEDS", "SCOTCH BONNET", "BIRDS EYE CHILLI", "HIMALAYAN PINK SALT", "CHARCOAL", "KOMBUCHA", "MATCHA TEA", "COLA", "MOON MILK", "MILKSHAKE", "MORINGA", "DRAGON FRUIT", "JACK FRUIT", "GUAVA", "DURIAN", "LYCHEE", "BLUE JAVA"];

var randArr = arr => arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)];
var word1 = document.querySelector(".inner-1");
var word2 = document.querySelector(".inner-2");
var button = document.querySelector(".button")

word1.style.cssText = 'color: yellow; background: green;'; // Is JS really needed?
word2.style.cssText = 'color: green; background: yellow;';

function randomText() {
  word1.textContent = randArr(w1);
  word2.textContent = randArr(w2);
}

button.addEventListener("click", randomText); // On click
randomText(); // and on init
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="header-1">Mash Made </div>
  <div class="header-2">in heaven</div>
</div>
<div class="outer-1">
  <div class="inner-1">Toast</div>
</div>
<div class="outer-2">
  <div class="inner-2">Gin</div>
</div>
<button class="button">Mash!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the word on click, not only once when the page loads

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    word1.textContent = leftArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * leftArr.length)];
    word2.textContent = rightArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * rightArr.length)];
    word1.setAttribute("style", "color: yellow");
    word2.setAttribute("style", "color: green");
    background1.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green");
    background2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow");
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an event listener on the button that will generate new values on each click as so:

```js
var leftArr = ["WHISKEY", "GIN", "VODKA", "APEROL", "CAMPARI", "LAGER", "ALE", "WINE", "MEZCAL", "TEQUILA", "PIZZA", "FRIED CHICKEN", "TOAST", "ICE CREAM", "CHIPS", "STEAK", "SALMON", "CAVIAR", "SUSHI", "PEANUT BUTTER", "MAYONAISE", "KETCHUP", "MARMITE"];

var rightArr = ["MUSTARD", "SOYA SAUCE", "WASABI", "SEAWEED", "TURMERIC", "VOLCANIC ASH", "WATER LILY SEEDS", "SCOTCH BONNET", "BIRDS EYE CHILLI", "HIMALAYAN PINK SALT", "CHARCOAL", "KOMBUCHA", "MATCHA TEA", "COLA", "MOON MILK", "MILKSHAKE", "MORINGA", "DRAGON FRUIT", "JACK FRUIT", "GUAVA", "DURIAN", "LYCHEE", "BLUE JAVA"];

var background1 = document.querySelector(".outer-1");
var background2 = document.querySelector(".outer-2");
var word1 = document.querySelector(".inner-1");
var word2 = document.querySelector(".inner-2");
var button = document.querySelector(".button")

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  word1.textContent = leftArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * leftArr.length)];
  word2.textContent = rightArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * rightArr.length)];
  word1.setAttribute("style", "color: yellow");
  word2.setAttribute("style", "color: green");
  background1.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green");
  background2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gen2</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="title">
    <div class="header-1">Mash Made </div>
    <div class="header-2">in heaven</div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-1">
    <div class="inner-1">Toast</div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-2">
    <div class="inner-2">Gin</div>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Mash!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

remove the color() function and put your button.addEventListener on global scope so the listener will catch every click